# Explain HOW the MVC Authorize Attribute performs AOP-like actions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, aop, postsharp

I've been trying to figure out how this works on a low-level:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Basically, the above code snippet seems to intercept calls to  the Index method, perform an authorization check, and throw and exception if not authorized. The exception prevents the code within the Index method from ever being invoked.

This seems very AOP-like, and is not something easily done in C#. If I were to implement my own class that extended System.Attribute, I would not have any interface to hook into pre or post invocation of the method my attribute decorates. So how does the MVC Authorize attribute do it, and how could I do it on my own?

PostSharp is a library that accomplishes the same thing using IL Weaving. Basically, at compile time, PostSharp scans the assembly for methods decorated with certain attributes, and then re-writes your code to wrap your method calls with other method calls.

Does the MVC framework also perform some kind of IL Weaving at compile time? Is it possible for me to perform my own IL Weaving? Or are there other techniques for applying the same AOP principles without complex IL Weaving?

I've tried to find information on IL Weaving but all I find are articles about PostSharp. I would prefer to stay away from PostSharp because of the Licensing hassles, but moreover, I just want to know how the heck they did it for my own growth as a developer. It's quite fascinating.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, grab the MVC source. If I recall, it's nothing so sophisticated as IL-weaving; the framework simply executes action method attributes prior to invoking the controller method. Request -> routing -> controller selection -> get relevant action method -> execute relevant attributes -> execute action method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the easiest way to understand it is by looking at the source code.

a basic explanation is that the mvc controller is not simply called like instance.method (in which case you would need postsharp to make the attributes work the same way)

there is a `ControllerActionInvoker` 
which has the method

```
 public virtual bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
 {
    ...
    // get all the filters (all that inherit FilterAttribute), inlcuding the authorize attribute
    FilterInfo filterInfo = GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
```

first all the filters that inherit `IAuthorizationFilter` are executed `(Authorize, ValidateAntiForgeryToken)`, after if auth succeeded the rest

```
AuthorizationContext authContext = InvokeAuthorizationFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthorizationFilters, actionDescriptor);
    //authContext.Result has value if authorization didn't succeed
if (authContext.Result != null)
{
    // the auth filter signaled that we should let it short-circuit the request
    InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, authContext.Result);
}
else
{
    if (controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest)
    {
        ValidateRequest(controllerContext);
    }

    IDictionary<string, object> parameters = GetParameterValues(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

    //invoke the action with filters here
    ActionExecutedContext postActionContext = InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ActionFilters, actionDescriptor, parameters);
    InvokeActionResultWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ResultFilters, postActionContext.Result);
}
```

Comment: Nice. And it's virtual so we can extend it if we wanted to add other types of attribute based filters that don't have to do with Authorization (such as logging). So without PostSharp or rolling our own IL Weaver, there's no way to auto-magically add AOP like attributes to any random class and invoke methods as usual. That makes sense.

Comment: you don't have to override it to add other filters: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: I guess it will be very difficult if I want my custom attribute to constrain my non-controller method like filter..